# How can I specify port range in socket.io-client?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am connecting to node server via another node server (using socket.io-client). After few connections, it gives me error:

`Connect ECONNREFUSED.`

I found that it tries to connect to unreachable port.

So, My questions:

1. Is it error from server side or client side?
2. If client side, how can I specify the range of ports in socket.io-client?

Comment: 'I found that it tries to connect to unreachable port.' No it doesn't. 'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at that port. You can only get that error *by* reaching that host.

Comment: @EJP: thanks for your reply. I didn't get this :** You can only get that error by reaching that host **. can you please explain little bit more about this?